How to get query result based on date and time in Oracle?
I have a simple query where I need to specify data from and until certain date and time. Result of my query is wrong, it doesn't limit data to specific date and time.
SELECT COLUMN1,TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') create_date
FROM T_TEST_DATA 
WHERE TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') >= '20/03/2024 22:57:44' AND 
TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') <= '21/03/2024 08:42:53'
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC


Dont do string-comparison on dates :D 
Just use the dates!
SELECT   COLUMN1,
         TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') create_date
FROM     T_TEST_DATA
WHERE    CREATE_DATE >= to_date('20/03/2024 22:57:44', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
AND      CREATE_DATE < to_date('21/03/2024 08:42:54', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC

Please also notice, that with date ranges you should ALWAYS compare against a greater upper bound, so that you cant get in trouble with leap days or leap seconds :)

Oracle does not support leap seconds and the OP is filtering with seconds precision so leap days appear to be irrelevant to the problem. In the OP's case they should be comparing with an inclusive upper-bound <= (rather than an exclusive upper-bound <) - so stating that you should ALWAYS use a greater upper-bound is wrong you can use <= when it is appropriate to the problem.

@MT0 > "the OP is filtering with seconds precision so leap days appear to be irrelevant to the problem"
Really we cant be sure here, because hopefully they use binds in their real statement.
So i wanted to state a general answer.
And i have always been safer with an exclusive upper-bound so i can only recommend this.
